# Convert given array to an HTML table in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, multidimensional-array, arraylist, html-table

Using angular 15
I have below array

```
header:any =['id','cid','NAME,'code','unit']
data: any = [
['2','110005001','abc test','0','NA'],
['2','110005001','abc test','0','NA'],
['2','110005001','abc test','0','NA']
```

]

I want to convert this to an html table data
I tried below html code but its not working

```
 this.data.forEach((lec) => {
      console.log(lec);
      this.Data.push({
        viewValue: lec,
        value: lec,
      });
    });
 <tr *ngFor="let r of Data">
 <td  >{{ r.value }}</td>
```

This gives output of one td taking all data with commas.
How to get the values correctly to an html table

Comment: You are pushing to `Data`, but in html you read `actualTableData`

Comment: Its a typo error. We are using Data only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is a nested array. You need the nested `*ngFor` to iterate each value in the array.

```
<tr *ngFor="let r of data">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let value of r">
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

If you look for a solution converting the values array into a set of objects:

```
this.actualTableData = this.data.map((x) => {
  let obj: { [key: string]: string } = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < this.header.length; i++) {
    obj[this.header[i]] = x[i];
  }

  return obj;
});
```

```
<tr *ngFor="let r of actualTableData">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let h of header">
    <td>{{ r[h] }}</td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wmeylv?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 2):

To convert the given array into an HTML table in Angular, you can use Angular's built-in directives and property bindings. You can iterate through the header and data arrays to generate the table structure. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
})
export class TableComponent {
  header: any = ['id', 'cid', 'NAME', 'code', 'unit'];
  data: any = [
    ['2', '110005001', 'abc test', '0', 'NA'],
    ['2', '110005001', 'abc test', '0', 'NA'],
    ['2', '110005001', 'abc test', '0', 'NA'],
  ];
}
```

In your corresponding HTML template, use Angular's *ngFor directive to generate the table structure:

```
<table>


 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let column of header">{{ column }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
      <td *ngFor="let cell of row">{{ cell }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```